# Need help on "this" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

When each button in the div is clicked, I want the parent div to disappear.  Instead of writing the onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'" for each button, I want to call a function done() to make my code cleaner, but my syntax did not work in the done().  Any ideas?

```
        <div id="arms_1" class="col_1">
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'">Done</button>
        </div>

        <div id="arms_2" class="col_2">
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <button type="button" onclick=done()>Done</button>
        </div>

        <div id="arms_3" class="col_3">
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <button type="button" onclick=done()>Done</button>
        </div>

<script>
        function done(){
            this.parentNode.style.display='none';
        };//done fuction ends
</script>
```

Comment: Does your query answered??

Comment: Your answer was the best answer, but I don't have enough reputation to vote it up.

Comment: This is What I have now:

<div id="abs_1">
 <button type="button" onclick=done(this)>Done</button>
</div>
   
<div id="abs_2" class="col_2 inv_div">
 <button type="button" onclick=done(this) >Done</button>
</div>

<script>
function done(para_1){
   para_1.disabled=true;   //set button to disable when clicked
}
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
    <div id="arms_3" class="col_3">
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <button type="button" onclick=done(this)>Done</button>
        </div>

<script>
        function done(obj){
            obj.parentNode.style.display='none';
        };//done fuction ends
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `(this)` to your `done`, and then add it to your function as well.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6hsr6a1/)

code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function done(obj) {
    obj.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<div id="arms_1" class="col_1">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'">Done</button>
</div>
<div id="arms_2" class="col_2">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="done(this);">Done</button>
</div>
<div id="arms_3" class="col_3">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="done(this);">Done</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) instead:

```
<script>
        function done(){
            this.parentNode.setAttribute('display', 'none);
        };//done function ends
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the function is not the same as `this` in the inline `onclick`. Try passing it in instead.

```js
function done(that){
            that.parentNode.style.display='none';
        };//done fuction ends
```

```html
<div id="arms_1" class="col_1">
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'">Done</button>
        </div>

        <div id="arms_2" class="col_2">
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <button type="button" onclick=done(this)>Done</button>
        </div>

        <div id="arms_3" class="col_3">
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <button type="button" onclick=done(this)>Done</button>
        </div>
```

Inside the function, `this` is the `Window` object. Inside the inline click handler, it refers to the `button`. Depending on the execution context you are in, `this` can refer to different things.